# What are the best practices for class, method, variable cases/names for objects in C# class library?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, namespaces

I'm a strong developer in some niche languages, and am organically learning C#, so trying to learn what are the best practices.

Can I get some feedback on what's best for the following sample code block where I'm building a Shopify integration for example.

```
namespace WMShopify
{
    // Is it common to have the namespace and class the same?
    public class WMShopify
    {
        // Are there different practices for private/public vars?
        public string APIKey { get; set; } // Capital
        public string password { get; set; } // lower case
        public string secretString { get; set; } // Camel
        private string _combinedVar; // Camel/underscore for private
    }

    // Should these be in a separate *.cs file?
    public class WMShopifyOrders
    {
        // Method capital/lower/camel?
        public int getOrderCount()
        {
            // lower/capital/camel?
            int localMemberVar = 0;

            return localMemberVar;
        }
    }

    // Should these be in a separate *.cs file?
    public class WMShopifyProducts
    {
        public List<string> getProductList()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found that the best practice is consistency. If you or your group has settled on a particular style guide, it should be followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice: Come up with a standard that everyone agrees on and follows.

Verdicts: Written InLine

```
namespace WMShopify
{
    // Is it common to have the namespace and class the same?

    //No, namespace should probably be the name of the project itself.
    public class WMShopify

    //this looks like a configuration class
    {
        // Are there different practices for private/public vars?
        public string APIKey { get; set; } // Capital
        public string password { get; set; } // lower case
        public string secretString { get; set; } // Camel
        private string _combinedVar; // Camel/underscore for private
    }

    // Should these be in a separate *.cs file?
    // I like to separate them because what happens when you have 100 classes, you just scroll forever?
    public class WMShopifyOrders
    {
        // Method capital/lower/camel?
        // I prefer capital
        public int getOrderCount()
        {
            // lower/capital/camel? Sure
            int localMemberVar = 0;

            return localMemberVar;
        }
    }

    // Should these be in a separate *.cs file? Yup
    public class WMShopifyProducts
    {
        public List<string> getProductList()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I ask about the classes being in different files is mainly for data contracts.  I use json2csharp.com to automatically create data contract classes from a Json string, and sometimes it's tons of little classes.

Comment: If you need generation of files, I'd suggest using t4. I have something similar and all classes are in one file, and they are just data contracts so it doesn't really matter all that much. In regular coding I have separate files though. In the above example I'd split them into individual files.

Comment: Great info. And t4 looks beyond me right now. I have a bunch of random Json files, so it appears from initially reading about it that I'd have to write up a template for each?  I need to read more on it.

Comment: No, you'd write one template that would generate everything from your json string. Learn t4. Well worth it, and it doesn't take much time at all.

Answer (score 1):

While this question will likely end up getting closed, MSDN does provide pretty extensive guidelines that most .NET developers follow to some degree:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx

Some highlights:

- Don't use abbreviations; if you do use acronoyms, capitalize only the first letter, e.g. `XmlReader`, not `XMLReader`.
- Use PascalCase for Methods and public Fields/Properties, use pascalCase for private fields, use _camelCase for private property backers.
- Keep classes to one file - one exception would be defining an interface and its default implementation in the same file
- Name methods using verbs (`GetSomething()`, `SendSomething()`, not `Something()`).
- Don't name properties with `Get` or `Set`, e.g. `Things` is good but not `GetThings`
- Name Booleans using "is" (`IsEnabled`, `IsReadOnly`, not `Enabled`).
- Generic parameters should generally use `T`, or `T(description)`, e.g. `TSource`, `TKey`, `T1/T2/T3`

Comment: The reason I ask about the classes being in different files is mainly for data contracts.  I use json2csharp.com to automatically create data contract classes from a Json string, and sometimes it's tons of little classes. Is this considered an exception?

Comment: Auto-generated classes are generally an exception because you won't be editing them or using refactoring tools on them.

Comment: Great info. I like these styles.