# Call a variable that is in a separate function

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, call, var

I am having some issues with retrieving the values of 2 variables. I am starting out with the variables being created during a button click in one function (`private void loadButton_lick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)`)

```
// Generate the folder name
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var stringChars = new char[20];
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
{
    stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}
var finalString = new String(stringChars);
// Folder name generated

// Generate the dll name
var dllChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var dllStringChars = new char[10];
var dllRandom = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < dllStringChars.Length; i++)
{
    stringChars[i] = dllChars[random.Next(dllChars.Length)];
}
var dllString = new String(stringChars);
// dll name generated
```

Now I call the variable "finalString" and "dllString" later in that same void to create a folder with the text that it creates and then downloading and renaming a file with the second name created.

```
// Making the folder and populating it
string path = "C:\\temp\\" + finalString + "\\";
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory;
}
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.33 Safari/537.36");
wb.DownloadFile("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-nPmtKfa70lE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/E66oeUI2kFw/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg", "C:\\temp\\" + finalString + "\\" + dllString +".dll"); // Downloads an image now for proof of concept but changes the extension to a .dll
// Folder is now populated
```

I now want to call the `finalString` and `dllString` variable one more time in a different function (public class) to use the items that were created in the last step, I cannot put the items from the public class into the previous function as it stops working. How can I go about making the variables `finalString` and `dllString` available to use in more than one function in the same C# Visual form? Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: declare your `finalString` and `dllString` as global variables meaning outside of any method scope so that it can be accessed through out your class.

Comment: @Ephraim how would I go about doing so? I need it to create the new folder and file name on each execution, but it appears I can only save int values globally and not var values. Maybe I'm missing something, I am fairly new to C# and still have a lot to learn

Comment: declare it as `string finalString = "";` and `string dllString = "";` outside of method scope.

Comment: How can I have it make the randomly generated folder and file names with that? I am so lost, I can't find any way to make this work how I need

Answer (score 0):

Have dllChars declared outside the method so in can be accessed by multiple methods. Consider the following example:

```
private string dllChars;

public main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
}

public void foo()
{
    dllString = new String(stringChars);
}

public void bar()
{
    if (dllChars.Equals("urmom"))
        MessageBox.Show("Hi, mom");
}
```

Having dllString set as public is not necessary if it doesn't need to be accessed outside of the class. It's generally a good idea to make your members private for security reasons and by the principles of object oriented programming, encapsulated design. However, if it needs to be read outside of the class, then change

```
private string dllChars;
```

to this:

```
public string dllChars
{
    set; private set;
}
```

if you actually want the variable to be modified outside of the class, then remove that "private"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `finalString` and `dllString` are inside a function like:

```
public void someFunction()
{
    var finalString = new String(stringChars);
    var dllString = new String(stringChars);
}
```

To access them on another method just declare them outside the function:

```
var finalString;
var dllString;

public void someFunction()
{
    finalString = new String(stringChars);
    dllString = new String(stringChars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access local variables outside the method.
The local variables created within the method are deleted as soon as the method comes to an end because because they are local they are no longer accessible and would only occupy space if they were not deleted.

The only way to access variables in multiple methods, which are called at different times, would be to create them outside the method:

```
public class YourClass()
{
    string finalString, dllString;
    private void loadButton_lick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do you stuff and set the values to finalString and dllString
    }

    private void YourSecondMethod()
    {
        // Happily acess finalString and dllString
    }
}
```

See too: [What are the best practices for class, method, variable cases/names for objects in C# class library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490480/what-are-the-best-practices-for-class-method-variable-cases-names-for-objects)